# Preprocessor macro calling all possible combinations

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I created a macro taking 3 conditions (as example, 8 in my real case):

```
#define FOO(A,B,C) \
  BOOST_PP_IF(A, a1, a2) \
  BOOST_PP_IF(B, b1, b2) \
  BOOST_PP_IF(C, c1, c2)
```

This works as I expect. Now I want to expand all the possibilities:

```
FOO(0,0,0)
FOO(0,0,1)
FOO(0,1,0)
FOO(0,1,1)
FOO(1,0,0)
FOO(1,0,1)
FOO(1,1,0)
FOO(1,1,1)
```

By this way, I have to write 8 lines. In my real case, I have to write 256 lines.

**How can I generate it directly with (boost) preprocessor tools ?**

MCV example with constructors declaration of a class `Foo` close to my real problem:

```
#define WRITE_FOO(A,B,C) \
  Foo(int a1 BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(A) BOOST_PP_IF(A, int a2, BOOST_PP_EMPTY()),
           double b1 BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(B) BOOST_PP_IF(B, double b2, BOOST_PP_EMPTY()),
           bool c1 BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(C) BOOST_PP_IF(C, bool c2, BOOST_PP_EMPTY()));
```

Then

```
class Foo {
  public:
    WRITE_FOO(0,0,0)
    WRITE_FOO(0,0,1)
    WRITE_FOO(0,1,0)
    WRITE_FOO(0,1,1)
    WRITE_FOO(1,0,0)
    WRITE_FOO(1,0,1)
    WRITE_FOO(1,1,0)
    WRITE_FOO(1,1,1)
  private:
    int a_1;
    int a_2;
    double b_1;
    double b_2;
    bool c_1;
    bool c_2;
};
```

is extended to

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int a1, double b1, bool c1);
    Foo(int a1, double b1, bool c1, bool c2);
    Foo(int a1, double b1, double b2, bool c1);
    Foo(int a1, double b1, double b2, bool c1, bool c2);
    Foo(int a1, int a2, double b1, bool c1);
    Foo(int a1, int a2, double b1, bool c1, bool c2);
    Foo(int a1, int a2, double b1, double b2, bool c1);
    Foo(int a1, int a2, double b1, double b2, bool c1, bool c2);
  private:
    int a_1;
    int a_2;
    double b_1;
    double b_2;
    bool c_1;
    bool c_2;
};
```

The implementation is similar to:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_FOO(A,B,C) \
  Foo::Foo(int a1 BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(A) BOOST_PP_IF(A, int a2, BOOST_PP_EMPTY()),
           double b1 BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(B) BOOST_PP_IF(B, double b2, BOOST_PP_EMPTY()),
           bool c1 BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(C) BOOST_PP_IF(C, bool c2, BOOST_PP_EMPTY())): \
    a_1(a1), \
    a_2(BOOST_PP_IF(A, a2, a1)), \
    b_1(b1),
    b_2(BOOST_PP_IF(B, b2, b1)), \
    c_1(c1),
    c_2(BOOST_PP_IF(C, c2, c1)) \
{}
```

Comment: part of me wants to reply "by not using macros"

Comment: @UKMonkey: if I don't use macro, I have to implement 256 versions of a class... But any constructive comment is welcome.

Comment: Can you use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if  ? Or can you make your class into a template?

Comment: Pls post your minimum C++ version. This can be solved with TMP. The higher your C++ version the conciser the solution will be.

Comment: I don't use C++11, but I can use enable_if from boost.

Comment: I can't use templates because the FOO macro generate constructors with variable number of arguments (I can't use C++11 for compatibility reason).

Comment: This is pretty much the perfect example of an XY problem ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy- problem   We're digging to understand your problem; to give you a more useful solution

Comment: Edit done with a example close to my real case.

Comment: I suppose (1) the actual types (instead of int, double, bool) are not (implicitly) convertible and

Comment: I am curious what use case would need 256 different constructors for the same class.

Comment: @user202729, no implicit convertion (actual types are own classes). No default value.

Comment: From what I can see, the cleanest route so far is to make all your optional arguments a `boost::optional<>` and then default them to `boost::none`.  The example you give though is a function; not a class - which is also a little confusing

Comment: @MaxLanghof: The main class is a generic class for mathematical testcases encoding. The constructor takes 8 pairs of data describing the test. In a lot a spacial cases, a pair is a duplication of the same data. Having all the constructors available makes the encoding really clearer (thousand of tests defined in a massive unit-testing procedure).

Comment: You call the macro "WRITE_FOO" - is this a big number of arguments so that you can stream data in different ways depending on what you're streaming?

Comment: I edited with a constructor example and implementation of the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linear-code solution that solves the question (although I would not suggest doing that in real code, use `template`s instead if possible)

```
#define W2(...) W1(__VA_ARGS__,0) W1(__VA_ARGS__,1)
#define W1(...) W0(__VA_ARGS__,0) W0(__VA_ARGS__,1)
W2(0) W2(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKLSjKT/7/XzklNS0zL1Uh3EhDT09PUyHcUCM@Pswx3jHIPTg@XscAQ8RQkwuuxxCqxwBDjwG6HqD5IHEjDUPN//8B)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answer your question (this does not use macros), but you can solve your problem instead using template metaprogramming.

Unfortunately variadic template is a C++11 feature. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683041)  contain more details about how to implement them for C++03 with pure C++, or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673493/c03-variadic-templates-using-boost) with Boost.

Also requires linear code.

```cpp
struct F{
    int i1,i2,d1,d2;

    template<class... Args>
    F(Args... args){init(args...);}

    void init(){} // base case
    template<class... Args>
    void init(int i1_,Args... args){i1=i1_;i2=i1_;init(args...);}
    template<class... Args>
    void init(int i1_,int i2_,Args... args){i1=i1_;i2=i2_;init(args...);}
    template<class... Args>
    void init(double d1_,Args... args){d1=d1_;d2=d1_;init(args...);}
    template<class... Args>
    void init(double d1_,double d2_,Args... args){d1=d1_;d2=d2_;init(args...);}

};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLNasQgFIXX8SmELhLBOmi7Gp2BbuYpCsVRGYREQzTdBJ89NcmE0rQE2m48x0889/qj2vbxptT4YJ2qe22E9SF2RjbnMWuvIrwMoLAuQkuxZVhTrBkHoIimaWsZjVC1DIEQAl@6WziD4lJNZgIyKxqss7GSC0I85a3v3mo4YzQkeDjAqwwGqjzsxH5uWpp5w5sy9JQht2yRTdHf5M7KdvLZ3/K176@1gfpb65qeMuSazfLP6NWynSo/HOCe5lvTyei7ClVIeRdifvwiRH08Kt9HISwVooRlNuxu9Er0RF5dyUGRQOLjdI2NtC4/cv4UA8WMpArxxT99mTGCnzeLK0jjBw) (gcc) or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLBaoQwFEXX@hWBLjRMxiHprCZxoJv5ikLJJKkENBETu5H8em3UkVJbBtpuvDdH3n0vPkXb7kXNTTU@aCPqXiqmrfOd4s15jNoLDy5DmmjjgcZIEyQxkoSmaeJV09bcKxbrnSuKAjx1lTunySWfzAR4VDhoo33OFwRpiKVvVkswYzgEcDiAK3cKiPi4E/tZtAzzgjZtcBkh1WSRTdPf5M5K7uSTv@VL219rBeS30SUuI6SSzPLP6NWSO11@uMAtzbaq4952OcyhsMb5uPzEeXk6Cdt7xjRmLANZNORm5ErkRJ5NRtMkpIGO02dsuDZxyfGnGDAiRcghXfzjlxMp0HHzcgVhfBevNa/cuI9jlGK3w/gD) (clang)

Requires the types to be assignable. You may want to add some `std::move` if you're worried about efficiency.